# Opening a modal window using jqueryUI in asp.net mvc 4 with VS2010

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to open a modal window in my asp.net mvc 4 project on click of a link. Nothing happens with the code that I have written. What am I missing? I have referenced these links in my site master.

```
<link type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/custom.css")" rel="Stylesheet" />   
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js")"></script>
```

Here is my code

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/SiteMaster.cshtml";
}


<div id="dialogMsg" title="I'm Title of dialog">
            Hello I'm dialog body.
</div>


<a href="#" id="thelink">Open Dialog</a>



<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {



        $("#dialogMsg").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Do something": function () {
                    var bValid = true;

                    $(this).dialog("close");

                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close: function () {
                allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
            }
        });




        $('#thelink')
        .click(function () {
            $('dialogMsg').dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed the `#`  on the selector that actually opens the dialog. See here:

```
$('#thelink')
    .click(function () {
        $('dialogMsg').dialog('open');
    });
```

Change it to:

```
$('#thelink')
    .click(function () {
        $('#dialogMsg').dialog('open');
    });
```